# Redux container render a collection which parameters to pass?

Tags: redux

We are using React+Redux and it's doing well. But there is one situation I never know which strategy to use.

When I need to loop over a collection, I could write:

1. Pass the element

Code:

```
render() {
  collection.map(element => <ElementItem key={element.id} element={element} />)
}
```

2. Pass the spread element

Code:

```
render() {
  collection.map(element => <ElementItem key={element.id} {...element} />)
}
```

3. Pass the ID

Code:

```
render() {
  collection.map(element => <ElementItem key={element.id} id={element.id} />)
}
```

and in `ElementItem.js`:

```
connect((state, ownProps) => {
  element: state.collection.find(_el => _el.id === ownProps.id)
})(ElementItem)
```

4. All in one file:

Code:

```
render() {
  collection.map(element => <li key={element.id}><p>{element.name}</p></li>)
}
```

- Solution #4 is not reusable so not much interesting.
- I don't like solution #2 since attributes are drowned in others
- I find #3 to be the cleanest since it is the one with lesser dependencies and forwarded props. The biggest trade off is that it feels lame to launch a `.find` for each `ElementItem`

So I guess it is the first one which wins. But I have the feeling this is not the *redux-way* of doing things, is it? If I pass the `element` parameter, why wouldn't I pass more? Then we are loosing all the benefits of isolating `container` from `presentation` components, don't we ?

Comment: You definitely need to add a key so `collection.map(element => <ElementItem key={element.id} element={element} />)` And it is perfecly "redux way": you have top-most container that knows about redux and simple presentational component `ElementItem` that can be easily tested and replaced if needed.

Comment: Thanks. You are right about the `key`s, I forgot them here. Gotcha for the `ElementItem`, but what if I need to pass many parameters? Forwarding them all feels heavy. Would this still make sense if I use `Connect` for other parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solutions #1 and #2 are perfectly fine, because in that case `ElementItem` is a presentational component and received its data from props.

Solution #3 makes no sense, because the component looping over the collection already got the collection part of the state (either because this component is connected to Redux, or because it got it from props).

In the redux documentation, there is an [example](https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react#designing-component-hierarchy) where they render a collection of todos: They use 2 presentational components: `Todo`, a single todo item, and `TodoList`, a list showing todos. Then there is a container component, `VisibleTodoList`, which computes the list of visible todos from the state and display them using `TodoList`. You could use the same strategy when you want to loop over a collection.

Another point: if you don't want to use `find` to get the right item, you could [normalize your state](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape#designing-a-normalized-state), so each 'collection table' stores the items in an object with the ids of the items as keys. This way, you could get the right item like this:

```
const element = state.collection[elementId];
```

Comment: Great answer thank you. I'll go for #1 to avoid spreading useless props. I'll consider normalizing also.